# Is there a way to change the name's font in the SO Jobs generated pdf to a serif one?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I find it to be hard to distinguish between a capital "i" and a lowercase "l" as is the case with my name, leading to pronunciation confusion.